# how to collapse objects in storybook controls

Tags: reactjs, object, storybook

I searched through storybook's documentation for react and I can't seem to find how to make the object control for my argument appear collapsed by default instead of having to collapse it manually.[image: this is how it appears I want it to be collapsed by default]

this is what I did

```
data: {
    control: { type: 'object' },
    table: { defaultValue: { summary: 'Object' } },
    collapsed: true, // I want to find out if there is something like this
  },
```

and this is what I was expecting
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The option to configure this does not exist, unfortunately. Inspired by this [comment](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/15900#issuecomment-1010174912) regarding having the RAW-view open by default, I made a somewhat hacky solution, query all the spans at the top level for collapsing their content and trigger a click using JavaScript.

In the file *manager.js* add the following to make this work:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  // Query the spans for collapsing objects.
  const objectCollapseSpans = [...document.querySelectorAll('.rejt-tree > .rejt-object-node > span')];
  // Query the spans for collapsing array of objects.
  const arrayCollapseSpans = [...document.querySelectorAll('.rejt-tree > .rejt-array-node > span')];
  const collapseSpans = [...arrayCollapseSpans, ...objectCollapseSpans];
  for (const span of collapseSpans) {
    if (span.className !== 'closed') {
      span.click();
    }
    span.className = 'closed'
  }
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
})
```